# Xamarin Android Support Library v4 can't add

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have started studying Android programming.I'm  using xamarin studio,When I try to add the library to my projects I got the following error:

[image]

And when I working on a project that has the same library.
The project appears as follows :
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you also expand your Packages folder? In fact, I would probably recommend adding packages through NuGet rather than the Components Store / manually adding them.

Comment: The packages folder contain :
xamarin.android.support.v4
xamarin.android.support.v7.appCompat
xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview

but this project is an open source project .. also not working..

Comment: I think the package you're trying to add is actually the package that already exists in the Packages folder - you shouldn't need to add it again.  If you're still struggling do you have a link to the project so I could take a look?

Comment: I do not know ..
But when I open a new project and I try to add libraries I get have the same problem
...
I have an old project have the same libraries also did not work ,do you want it to  take a look ?